# Is there a way, using scikit-learn, to plot the OOB ROC curve for random forest?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

Using Python and sklearn I want to plot the ROC curve for the **out-of-bag (oob)** true positive and false positive rates of a random forest classifier.

I know this is possible in R but can't seem to find any information about how to do this in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You need `.oob_decision_function_`that returns the prediction probabilities for the out of bag samples after fitting.

P.S: This is available in `scikit-learn==0.22`

Small example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import plot_roc_curve
from sklearn.datasets import load_wine
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = load_wine(return_X_y=True)
y = y == 2

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=42, oob_score=True)
rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)

from sklearn import metrics
pred_train = np.argmax(rfc.oob_decision_function_,axis=1)
metrics.roc_auc_score(y_train, pred_train)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I want to plot the ROC curve.
Would something like this make sense?
`probas = rfc.oob_decision_function_`

`fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_train, probas[:, 1])`

`plt.plot(fpr, tpr)`

Comment: yes! this is what you need in any case: `rfc.oob_decision_function_`

Comment: so just to make sure I understood, `rfc.oob_decision_function_`returns the prediciton probabilities for the out of bag samples, right?